# Soap Exception message returns two different error messages from two different servers for the same asmx service

Tags: .net, service, asmx

We have an ASMX service and the same code deployed in two different servers but whenever there is an exception or error happening in one server the exception message returned is different for both servers.Specifically the fault string is different.Below are the sample messages returned on an error from both servers

**Message from First Server**

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
SOAP Response: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Fault occurred</faultstring>
      <faultactor>http://bbbonline.consumerservice/service.asmx?op=FileComplaint</faultactor>
      <detail>ErrorOccured at so and so..</detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Message from Second Server**

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
SOAP Response: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>
        System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Fault occurred
        at BBBOnline.Application.MyService.MySoapException(XmlNode ErrorNode)
        at BBBOnline.Application.MyService.FileAComplaint(String SSN, String Buisness, String Issue, String Reason, String date)
      </faultstring>
      <faultactor>http://bbbonline.consumerservices/service.asmx?op=FileComplaint</faultactor>
      <detail>ErrorOccured..</detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In both the messages above the FaultString is different,but the code in both servers is absolutely same.

Comment: Just to let you know more..the servers are all win2k8 and these services are being consumed by a Java App which is the UI for our application and that is deployed on a different server. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: ASMX web services are a legacy technology that should not be used for new development. Among other things, they don't properly support SOAP faults.

Comment: we cannot start developing the services from the scracth to fix this minor issue becoz it contains about 28 different web methods and is in use..could somebody help me with a better answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is typically caused by differences in the web.config files on the two servers. In particular, look to see if the `<customErrors>` elements are different.

If the web.configs are identical, look for differences in the `machine.config` files on the two servers.